# How to multithread a process method

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to using multi threading to process a list of results faster. I tried using a parallel for each but when the process method is run I do not recieve the correct results.

```
private IEnumerable<BulkProcessorResult> GetProccessResults(List<Foo> Foos)
{
    var listOfFooLists = CreateListOfFooLists(Foos);

    var bulkProcessorResults = new List<BulkProcessorResult>();
    Parallel.ForEach(listOfFooLists, FooList =>
    {
        foreach (var Foo in FooList)
        {
            var processClaimResult = _processor.Process(Foo);
            var bulkProcessorResult = new BulkProcessorResult()
            {
                ClaimStatusId = (int) processClaimResult.ClaimStatusEnum,
                Property1 = Foo.Property1
            };
            bulkProcessorResults.Add(bulkProcessorResult);
        }
    }); 

    return bulkProcessorResults;
}
```

If I use a normal forEach I get the correct output. If I use the above code I get status' of all 2 when there should be three with the status of 1 and one status of 3.

I am really new to threading so any help would be great.

Comment: What is the languge? You should add it to the tag.

Comment: You might want to look at e.g. [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) as an intermediate store. `List<T>` isn't safe to manipulate (e.g. by calling `Add`) from multiple threads. Anything could (and probably will) happen.

Comment: The first problem I see is that you have multiple concurrent threads adding items to `buldProcessResults`. That's going to cause a problem because `List.Add` is not designed to work with multiple concurrent updates. You'll need to protect that with a lock, or use some type of concurrent data structure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever add that as an answer when I use ConcurrentQueue<T> it fixes all my issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious issue is that you're working with multiple threads (okay, this is somewhat hidden by calling `Parallel.ForEach`, but you should be aware that it achieves parallelism by using multiple threads/tasks) but you're using a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), which isn't a thread-safe collection class:

> A `List<T>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with one or more write accesses, the only way to ensure thread safety is to lock the collection during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization

Rather than implementing your own synchronization, though, and whilst not altering much else in your code, I would switch to using a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx):

```
private IEnumerable<BulkProcessorResult> GetProccessResults(List<Foo> Foos)
{
    var listOfFooLists = CreateListOfFooLists(Foos);

    var bulkProcessorResults = new ConcurrentQueue<BulkProcessorResult>();
    Parallel.ForEach(listOfFooLists, FooList =>
    {
        foreach (var Foo in FooList)
        {
            var processClaimResult = _processor.Process(Foo);
            var bulkProcessorResult = new BulkProcessorResult()
            {
                ClaimStatusId = (int) processClaimResult.ClaimStatusEnum,
                Property1 = Foo.Property1
            };
            bulkProcessorResults.Enqueue(bulkProcessorResult);
        }
    }); 

    return bulkProcessorResults;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `ConcurrentBag<T>`.

Comment: @JimMischel Do you have any experience that `ConcurrentBag` will be more efficient in a situation like this? As far as I know, `ConcurrentBag` works best when each thread is *both* producer and consumer, which is not the case here.

Comment: @svick: I have no information about the speed of `ConcurrentBag` relative to `ConcurrentQueue`. I was just mentioning another option.

Answer (score 1):

How about treating the entire thing as a Parallel Linq query?

```
private IEnumerable<BulkProcessorResult> GetProccessResults(List<Foo> Foos)
{
  var listOfFooLists = CreateListOfFooLists(Foos);
  return listOfFooLists.AsParallel()
                       .SelectMany(FooList => FooList)
                       .Select(Foo =>
                            new BulProcessorResult {
                               ClaimStatusId = (int)_processor.Process(Foo),
                               Property1 = Foo.Property1
                            }).ToList();
}
```